# Segmentation Fault Core dump with C on ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, segmentation-fault

I have a problem with some line of codes I've written in plain C.
It worked fine on windows, but on ubuntu there's an error saying "Segmentation Fault (core dumped)". I've searched for answers but there's too many problem that can caused that error.

```
char line[80];
char sett[50][80];
int index=0;
static const char filename[] = "squid.conf";
FILE *file = fopen ( filename, "r" );

while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ) 
{
    strcpy(sett[index],line);
    index++;
}
```

I just simply want to write the whole file to an 2 dimensional array, line by line.
If I quote the `//strcpy(sett[index],line);` the program runs fine with no errors.

Comment: How many lines are in your input file?  If its more than 50, you'll write beyond the end of `sett`

Comment: Hoe many lines are there in the file? If you run in a debugger, it will stop at the `strcpy` line, and most likely the `index` variable will be larger than 50.

Comment: why not doing `fgets` straight into `sett[index]`?

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, maybe your squid.conf have more than 50 lines, (my squid.conf have 4948 lines)

You can count lines before and malloc(nlines * 80) or you can use a linked list:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct sett {
    char value[80];
    struct sett *next;
} sett;

int main(void)
{
    char line[80];
    sett *curr, *first = NULL, *prev = NULL;
    static const char filename[] = "squid.conf";
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) {
        curr = malloc(sizeof(sett));
        if (curr == NULL) {
            perror("malloc");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (prev) {
            prev->next = curr;
        } else {
            first = curr;
        }
        strcpy(curr->value, line);
        curr->next = NULL;
        prev = curr;
    }
    fclose(file);
    curr = first;
    while (curr) {
        printf("%s", curr->value);
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        free(prev);
    }
    return 0;
}
```